# Customize quick launch for groups [SharePoint 2013]

Tags: groups, quick-launch

I have created multiple SharePoint user groups with different permission levels (i.e. different lists & libraries). Now I would like to customize the quick launch bar for the various groups to reflect the permissions.
Is this possible? And if, could you please point towards the optimal solution.

Thank you!

Comment: @Akhoy thank you for your comment. I indeed have configured the inheritance accordingly. However I do not want to show all the other folders/ sub-projects to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With quick launch you probably mean the structural navigation on the left side, right? 
The only solution, that comes to mind is to work with the navigation settings (/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx) on your site. There you can edit the audience of each link in the quicklaunch. 
Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you Nils. Yes, I was referring to the navigation menu on the left side. Unfortunately I do not find an option to further specify. Could this be as I have set-up a Team Site?

Comment: This works for me, when clicking on edit. Do you have a Foundation version?

Comment: Many thanks again. It seems I was blind the first time. However now I noticed that for audience targeting to be fully functional on links the User Profile Service needs to be enabled. Which needs to be done centrally via the SharePoint server.